# The "possible spam" banner for suggested edits is misaligned

Tags: bug, design, suggested-edits, spam-detection

On this banner ([seen  here](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/212789) on spam edits):

[image: banner showing orange text reading "Our system has identified this edit as possible spam; please review carefully" towards the bottom of a gray banner]
... the text is aligned to the bottom of the banner, where it should probably be in the middle.

Just putting the text in `<p>` tags (like the protected and closed banners) seems to fix it (though the text may be larger than desired):

[image: banner showing orange text reading "Our system has identified this edit as possible spam; please review carefully" in the center of a gray banner]

Can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to have been fixed without feedback (on this question), I'll add an answer here to mark the question as answered.

---

There is now a new banner, using its own CSS class (`info-box`), which has correct padding and centering

> [image]
>
> ---
>
> ```
> .info-box {
>     background-color: #FFF1D0;
>     margin-top: 1em;
>     padding: 0.5em;
>     font-size: 14px;
>     text-align: center;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use padding top and bottom to fix this problem:

```
.question-status {
     text-align:center;
     padding:10px 0px;
}
```