# "No longer reproducible" close reason uses much smaller font sizes compared to the other close reasons

Tags: bug, design, vote-to-close, close-dialog

This seems to have popped up today.  The "No longer reproducible" close reason now has its own header and the explanation text is much smaller:

[image]

(Might need to zoom in a touch or test it yourself to really get it.)  Is this part of a leaky upcoming change, or just a bug?

Comment: It was changed to the new form of community-specific close reasons. See the top answer to [Can we replace the "no longer reproducible" close reason with a \[status-obsolete\] tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343206/can-we-replace-the-no-longer-reproducible-close-reason-with-a-status-obsolete), the paragraph beginning with *In the interim before the new close reason is created, and for any questions currently closed with the old reason, we can make a slight update to the existing close reason*.

Comment: @Sonic True... but I've never seen it like that before.

Comment: The new forms are used on Stack Overflow. The paragraph also has a link to how the new form works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should we update/clarify our help center with respect to other sites and teams?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/362584/282094)

Comment: The “blatantly off-topic” flag also has the same CSS, as well as the other community-“unspecific” flags.