# I'm repeatedly getting 409 and 500 HTTP responses when trying to edit comments

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, comment-edits

I'm getting this on SO, MSE, and other network sites.

The 500 error returns the content of the 404 page.

What happened?

Comment: I've found this too. They do work eventually.

Comment: @rene I just noticed this myself, and I don't have any userscripts, or anything else like that.

Comment: We're on it, thanks for reporting!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fix is shipping to prod right now

Update - this is now fixed on Prod

Comment: @starball I wrote a bit about it in here - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343206/can-we-replace-the-no-longer-reproducible-close-reason-with-a-status-obsolete/368188#368188